# DRBD network requirements

Tags: drbd

We currently have a DRBD based replication on an pair of Asterisk servers, where we use DRBD for file and MySQL data replication on an active/passive usage scenario, using protocol B (semi-synchronous). Heartbeat handles the failover.

We are currently syncing over a back-to-back Gbit Ethernet, that will now be replaced with some switches and a fiber interconnect, as we would like to have active and passive server on different (physical) locations.

What are the network requirments of the interconnect in order to archive a proper DRBD setup? I would like to find out what the requirements are in terms of latency, packet loss, jitter, etc. (ignoring bandwidth, as that would be a function of the amount of data needed to be synced).

I've seen Linbit offers "DRBD Proxy" for WAN scenarios, but thats not the case here, it's still a LAN enviroment with (relative) low latency and packet loss. Or stated differently: when does it become neccesary to use DRBD Proxy, how "bad" should the network be?

[This similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/353733/drbd-or-similiar-raid-over-net-on-slow-limited-networks) touches the issue, but does not state specific requierements or real-world limits.